# RenamingDelegatingContext not creating a test database

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-sqlite, junit4

I am trying to write test cases for my app database. This is what I do in the setup method:

```
 @Before
    public void testCaseSetUp() {
        RenamingDelegatingContext context = new RenamingDelegatingContext(getTargetContext(), "test_");
        dbController = new DBController(context);
        dbController.open();
    }
```

**DBController.java**

```
public DBController(Context c) {
            context = c;
        }

        public DBController open() throws SQLException {
            dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
```

RenamingDelegatingContext does not create a new test database instead uses the existing db file. This is causing my test cases to fail as I already have data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you recreate your `SQLiteOpenHelper` somewhere inside your `DBHelper` class? From the looks of it the latter is a singleton, so I can assume you're not recreating it every time. You should do so in your `@Before` method, because the idea behind using a `RenamingDelegatingContext` here is that it deletes old databases before opening a new one.

Also it's a good practice to close the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class after your tests. Something like:

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

If this doesn't work, please post your `DBHelper` class to verify it's ok.

Comment: that is a good catch. I am using a singleton pattern for my helper class. Greta thank you.

Comment: Is there a way where I can create a separate test database just for testing and then destroy it in teardown. This way I don't touch the production database ?

Comment: Exactly using `RenamingDelegatingContext` is the way to go. When you use this context in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` it'll create a test database that has nothing to do with your real one! If the answer helped you, perhaps you can upvote it - this way other people will know that's the solution.